How i can detect screen record in flutter?
I've been trying to prevent screen recording in Flutter by using the flutter_window_manager package and native code to set a secure flag. However, both methods are ineffective because they result in a black screen in the recorded video, while the audio is still captured, which doesn't serve my purpose.
I've also explored various detection techniques, but I haven't found a solution that prevents both the video and audio from being recorded, or prevents the recording altogether.
If anyone knows a viable solution or any approach that could help me achieve this, I would greatly appreciate your guidance
.............................................
